# Read latest txt in a Folder R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with stock files from a repository, a new file is generated every day:

*For example:
"stock2021-11-05.txt"*

I need to read the last generated file, or in its defect read all the files that begin with the word stock, join them.

I currently use the following code:

```
fileList <- list.files( pattern=  "*.txt")
```

But this brings me all the txt files from the repository and not just the ones that start with the word stock.

I would appreciate a help with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you managed to filter out files which are not .txt files. Two steps are missing. A possible *fileList* now could be:

```
fileList <- c("stock2021-11-05.txt",
              "stock2020-11-15.txt",
              "stock2021-02-05.txt",
              "vwxyz2018-01-01.txt")
```

1 - Filter stock-files

```
> fileList_stock <- grep("^stock", fileList, value = TRUE)
> fileList_stock
[1] "stock2021-11-05.txt" "stock2020-11-15.txt" "stock2021-02-05.txt"
```

2 - Get latest file

```
> sort(fileList_stock, decreasing = TRUE)[1]
[1] "stock2021-11-05.txt"
```

1+2 - Wrapper function

```
> get_last_stock_file <- function(x){
+   grep("^stock", x, value = TRUE) %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE) %>% .[1]
+ }
> get_last_stock_file(fileList)
[1] "stock2021-11-05.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
list.files(pattern = "stock.*\\.txt")
```

to find all files that begin with "stock" and end with ".txt"

Check out this REGEX cheat sheet from the stringr package to learn more:
https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/main/strings.pdf